# Syntax error: Port is not defined Verilog file

Tags: verilog

```
module ram_1_verilog(input EnA,input EnB,
  input WeA, input WeB,
  input Oe,
  input clk);
 
LINE :25   input [7:0] Addr_a;      //Error
LINE :26   input [7:0]Addr_b;       //Error
LINE :27   input reg [7:0] dout1;   //Error
LINE :28   output reg [7:0] dout_2; //Error
    
reg [7:0] ram [255:0];
    
always @(posedge clk)
begin
  if(EnA == 1 && WeA == 1) begin 
LINE 35  ram(Addr_a) <= dout1;      //Error 
  end
end
    
always @(posedge clk)
begin
  if(EnB == 1 && WeB == 0) begin
  LINE : 44 dout_2 <= ram(Addr_b);  //Error
  end
end
endmodule
```

Errors:

```
Syntax error near "<=". line 35
Line 25: Port Addr_a is not defined Verilog file C:/Documents and Settings/verilog_examples/ram_1_verilog.v ignored due to errors
Line 25: Port declaration not allowed in ram_1_verilog with formal port declaration list
Line 26: Port Addr_b is not defined
Line 26: Port Addr_b is not defined
Line 26: Port declaration not allowed in ram_1_verilog with formal port declaration list
Line 27: Port dout1 is not defined

Line 27: Non-net port dout1 cannot be of mode input
Line 27: Port declaration not allowed in ram_1_verilog with formal port declaration list
Line 28: Port dout_2 is not defined
Line 28: Port declaration not allowed in ram_1_verilog with formal port declaration list
Line 35: dout1 is not a task

Line 44: ram is not a function.
Line 44: ram expects 0 arguments.
Line 44: Cannot assign an unpacked type to a packed type.
```

I'm working on a dpram, but I'm getting errors in Verilog.  Please help me figure out the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Lines 35 and 44 - you've made twice the same mistake, explained to you by Tim.
2. Lines 25-28 are flagged, because `Addr_a`, `Addr_b`, `dout1` and `dout_2` are not declared in port declaration list and then are defined as `input`/`output`.

Comment: yes sir,declaration inside the module bracket is ANSI style declaration,  it is same thing if we declare outside the bracket right????

Comment: @user3751971: no. You can skip `input`/`output` word in the bracket and then define signal, as `input`/`output`, outside the bracket. But it has to be in port declaration list.

Comment: Thanks a lot, and by the way the values which I'm trying to initialize, they are not getting stored inside the ram addrerss ?? in the modelsim it is showing XXXXXXX.....XXX. but the logic look's same in  predefined codes when i surfed the internet

Comment: How do you initialize it?

Comment: ram(Addr_a) <= dout1;

Answer (score 2):

One issue I see is that you are attempting to do array selection with parenthesis, when it should use square brackets:

Change from:

```
LINE 35         ram(Addr_a) <= dout1;       // error
```

to:

```
LINE 35         ram[Addr_a] <= dout1;
```

I don't see any errors on line 25-28, not sure why those are being flagged.